# before_destroy for model that destroys dependent records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation like this:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services, dependent: :destroy
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_weeks, dependent: :destroy
end

class ModelWeek < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :prevent_destroy, if: :default?

  private

  def prevent_destroy
    false
  end
end
```

When I try to destroy a shop, I get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed: Failed to destroy the record` because it starts destroying the associated records first, and it gets prevented by the callback in the ModelWeek.

I could easily unset default for ModelWeek when destroying a shop, only if I could catch it. `before_destroy` in the `Shop` model does not get triggered prior to when the above mentioned exception is raised.

So, is there a way to catch this in Shop model, or if not, is it possible to "know" in the ModelWeek that destruction was triggered by a parent? I investigated parsing the caller, but it offers nothing useful, and it would be messy anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and testing, this is what I came up with:

This is the order in which the methods are being called (`do_before_destroy` are any methods specified in the `before_destroy` callback):

- Shop.destroy
- Service.destroy
- ModelWeek.destroy
- ModelWeek.do_before_destroy
- Service.do_before_destroy
- Shop.do_before_destroy

So, I can deal with anything preventing the destruction of a child (ModelWeek) in the destroy method of a parent (Shop):

```
# Shop
def destroy
  # default is a scope
  ModelWeek.default.where(service_id: self.services.pluck(:id)).each do |m| 
    m.unset_default 
  end

  super
end
```

After that nothing prevents destruction of the child and the chain continues unprevented.

---

UPDATE

There is even better, cleaner solution, without a need for overriding the `destroy` of the parent and doing any queries:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services, dependent: :destroy, before_remove: :unset_default_week

  private

  def unset_default_week(service)
    service.model_weeks.default.unset_default
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved this problem by using a funny hack, 
you just need to put the `before_destroy` line
before the **association line**
and it will run `before_destroy` before deleting the associations

Answer (score 1):

The modern solution is to use a `before_destroy` callback in the parent model with `prepend: true` option, making the callback trigger before the destruction callback that's defined under the hood by `dependent: :destroy` on association.

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_weeks, dependent: :destroy

  before_destroy :handle_model_weeks, prepend: true

  private

  def handle_model_weeks
    # special handling here
  end
end
```

See also a [Rails thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/670) on this.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work. Calling `self.model_weeks` inside of `handle_model_weeks` returns an empty array. I think it's firing too late, even with `prepend: true`

Comment: @alex Surprising and unfortunate. As the thread mentions, an even stronger approach is to define the `before_destroy` callback *before* the association. Anything to avoid polluting ModelWeek with logic about cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Since rails has destruction chain from related children to parent, it really makes sense, right? To make it easy, we can overwrite the destroy method in ModelWeek like this:

```
class ModelWeek < ActiveRecord::Base
  # before_destroy :prevent_destroy, if: :default?
  def destroy
    unless default?
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How does this make it different? I need to prevent destroying the default ModelWeek unless the destruction was requested by the parent (a Service). How can I know that within a destroy method of ModelWeek?

Comment: If as your description, we remove the dependent, because it doesn't work like it should work. Do deletion in controller or service object, I think!

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to do it manually, I want it managed by rails, and I found out how, in fact 2 solutions. Please take a look at the answer I posted. You gave me the idea for the first one, but in the end I went with the second one, as it is cleaner.